# Jquery Mobile Panel visible on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile's panel widget and for some odd reason When I click on a link inside the panel, it get the normal transistion but the panel remains visible while the rest of the content fades out. Here's the markup

```
<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="panel" id="panel">
<ul data-role="listview">

<li><a href="../index.html" data-ajax="false" 
data-transistion="none">Link</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="header"></div>

<div data-role="content"></div>

<div data-role="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Everything is written correctly but for some reason I'm getting this effect. It doesn't happen on any other page with a panel but this one. Could this be a problem with my Jquery files or my CSS? Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: You have to share more code. I tried the same code on jsfiddle and its working well.

Comment: Are you using the default themes with jqm? I'm starting to think that because I'm using a custom theme, that it may be messing with it. Are you placing the panel before the header or after the footer?

Comment: Try it with jQM standard CSS styles, and check if the same happens.

Comment: yeah even with the jqm styles I'm having the same issue. It maybe noteworthy that I'm using this in combination of phonegap 2.6 to make an ios app.

Comment: are using `data-ajax=false` and `data-transition=none` for the rest of pages?

Comment: yeah I kinda have to since the app is linking several multi-paged jqm documents

Comment: @user2055617 are u setting some transition for the panel when it hides away?

Comment: No but I have a default transition set to slide in the jqm.js, could that be is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but I re-downloaded my copy of jquery and jquery mobile and it seemed to fix any issues I was having. Could possibly be because I changed the default transition but who knows. The issue is fixed so I'm happy